# Change the color of an actionbar on an activity from a package

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I have an Android app that uses a third-party library to perform some camera functions. And it works great! The library displays a new activity that allows you to use the camera and access the photo-reel.

However, I would like to see if I can change the color of the `ActionBar` in the activity. Since the activity is inside the library, the only thing I have access to (object-wise) is the intent that is created using the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, GalleryActivity.class);
```

**Is there any way to access the `activity` from an `intent`?** And then from the activity, get to the `ActionBar` to change the color of it? Or would I be required to pull the source directly into my own project and modify it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you would accomplish by changing the bar color before you create the activity, but heres how you would do it once it exists.

You would do this programmatically in your onCreate() method.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(*your color here*);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Right, but since this activity is inside a third-party library (I did not create `GalleryActivity`), I don't have access to the `onCreate()`.

Comment: Well you wouldn't access that class anyway. You would make a new activity that extends that class, then you will be able to Override its 'onCreate()' method

Comment: Ah ok. I'll try that.